headerShadowVisible: false crashes design
Why does adding options={{ headerShown: false }} makes all the layout overlap the android toolbar. This error after implementing the Tabs Menu.
.app\_layout.jsx
import {Stack} from "expo-router";

const StackLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen
                name="(tabs)"
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                }}
            />
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default StackLayout;

app\(tabs)\_layout.jsx
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";

export default () => {
  return (
    <Tabs>
       <Tabs.Screen name="home" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Tabs>
  );
};

And \app\(tabs)\home.jsx - This is the page that after adding the Tab Navigation floats outside the safeareaview
import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView, View} from "react-native";

// Configs
import {COLORS, SIZES} from "../../constants/theme";

// Components
import Welcome from "../../components/Welcome/Welcome";
import CardMenu from "../../components/CardMenu/CardMenu";
import EncomendasList from "../../components/EncomendasList/EncomendasList";

// Define Home component
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.pureWhite}}>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        padding: SIZES.medium,
                    }}
                >
                    <Welcome/>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        padding: 0,
                    }}
                >
                    <CardMenu/>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        padding: SIZES.medium,
                    }}
                >
                    <EncomendasList/>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

// Export Home component
export default Home;```


The content remaing inside the `safeareaview`

